# Is there a function that returns with the time passed since an event? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The function `ta.barssince()` returns with the bars happened after a certain event but it's dependent on the timeframe. Is there a similar function to get the seconds/minutes passed since the event? Or a workaround?

My goal is to skip the first `x` minutes after the beginning of new period (from the VWAP indicator), no matter which time-zone or timeframe we are in. (This moment can be easily addressed by watching VWAP Band Width because it suddenly drops near to zero once in a day.)

So it could be like this example conceptual code:

```
BooleanVariable = ta.minutessince(VwapBandWidth < VwapBandWidth[1]/10) > 60
```

I found two functions: `minute` and `minute()` but couldn't find the way how to use it for this purpose, how to tell them to count the minutes since the event instead of the year 1970.

Comment: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#can-i-time-the-duration-of-a-condition

Comment: Thank you! Found it, though, it's V4. Still struggling with the conversion. Is there a way to update all the codes there to V5? Not just for me but anyone.

Comment: It is in progress but will take some time. New Q&As will be added too.

Answer (score 0):

V5 code, based on the code found [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-convert-the-current-resolution-in-a-numeric-format):

```
// ————— Converts current chart timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_resInMinutes() =>
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60 : timeframe.isminutes ? 1. : timeframe.isdaily ? 60. * 24 : timeframe.isweekly ? 60. * 24 * 7 : timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375 : na)
    _resInMinutes

f_htfLabel(_txt, _y, _color, _offsetLabels) =>
    _t = int(time + f_resInMinutes() * _offsetLabels * 60000)
    var _lbl = label.new(_t, _y, _txt, xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, #00000000, label.style_none, color.lime, size.large)
    if barstate.islast
        label.set_xy(_lbl, _t, _y)
        label.set_text(_lbl, _txt)
        label.set_textcolor(_lbl, _color)

// ————— Get current res in float minutes.
resInMinutes = f_resInMinutes()
// ————— Plot label.
//f_htfLabel(str.tostring(resInMinutes, 'Current res in minutes (float): #.0000'), ta.sma(high + 3 * ta.tr, 10)[1], color.lime, 3)

//Minutes past since an event (Boolean variable) called "SomewhatEvent":
MinutesPastSinceAnEvent = ta.barssince(SomewhatEvent) * resInMinutes
```